# Meaning of “in capitals”

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

> As I think back to that interaction in Brussels – with that gentleman in a suit saying, “your industry is just looking for a lifeline.”
> I remember my response was instinctive. I told him “It’s not our industry looking for a lifeline. It’s our industry offering the world a lifeline.” That’s the truth – but it’s not enough. We need to show him – and **the many others in capitals** across the world. And while I’m fairly sure I didn’t convince him, I know we cannot afford to be excluded from the conversation any longer. [IOGP](https://www.iogp.org/blog/benefits-of-oil-and-gas/opinions/the-conversation-were-not-having/)

What is the meaning of “capitals”?

At first, I thought of the capital letters and it could mean a stronger manner in a figurative sense. But when I search the dictionary, Longman says as follows:

> Capital: 4. a place that is a centre for an industry, business, or other activity
> [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/capital)

Comment: What relation does Brussels have to Belgium? When you have the answer, consider London, Paris, Canberra, Ottawa, and Tokyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning you found seems to fit the description of *people living in capitals*, and that the speaker needs to show the many others in major cities and centers.

Comment: Definition 1 (a capital city) fits the context better, as Michael implies!

Comment: The answer seems ungrammatical unless you clarify that "the many others" refer to the businessman in a suit.